# Get data from JSON API and display it in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to use this **minecraft server API (JSON)**, to show in my webpage, something like... *Right now there are (players) connected*.
The JSON file looks like this (external):

```
{
"status": true,
"players": {
    "online": 534,
    "max": 900
},
"cache": 1442690473 }
```

I want to fetch the data players (online) and display it on a html paragraph.... Using JavaScript or Jquery. I searched some solutions, using *getJSON*, but I couldn't make it work..
I tried using AJAX to make a request...

```
  // AJAX Request to JSON
              $.ajax({
                  url: "https://mcapi.ca/query/mythalium.com/players",
                  // Handle as Text
                  dataType: "text",
                  success: function(data) {
                      // Parse JSON file
                      var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                      //Store data into a variable
                      // Display Players
                      $('#players').html('Currently there are: ' + json.players.now ' users');
                  }
      });
```

And then display it using:

```
 <span id="results"></span>
```

Why is not working? Nothing is being showed...

Comment: Can you show us your attempts?

Comment: There are lots and lots of tutorials available for doing this. Just saying `here's some data` is not a proper question request here without showing your attempts to solve this yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your AJAX success callback to:

```
success: function(data) {
    // Parse JSON file
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    //Store data into a variable
    // Display Players
    $('#results').html('Currently there are: ' + json.players.online' + users');
}
```

The problems are you're selecting the wrong `span` element - `#players` instead of `#results` and you're referencing the wrong JSON property - `json.players.now` instead of `json.players.online` like in the sample response you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Datatype should be JSON.

Check this video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEYx8dQr_cQ

You should be fine then.