# Loading XHR response data to index HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-web-api, ecmascript-6, xmlhttprequest

I have a .NET api endpoint that returns anonymous data and client side received these either through Promise like this:

```
function getDataByPromise(method, url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText,
        });
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
      reject({
        status: this.status,
        statusText: xhr.statusText,
      });
    };
  });
}
```

or through Callback like this:

```
function getDataByCallback(method, url, done) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url);
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    done(null, xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function () {
    done(xhr.response);
  };
```

or through Async/Await

```
async function getDataByAsyncAwait() {
  try {
    console.log("By Async Await");
    await getDataByPromise(method, url);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

or through normal XHR like this:

```
function getDataByXHR(method, url) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log("By XHR: ");
    console.log(xhr.response);
    let gameSettings = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    this.data = gameSettings;
    waitAsyncAwait(this.data);
    waitPromise(this.data);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function () {
    console.error("An error occur getting the XMLHttpRequest");
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

How can I display these JSON object in the html file either by pushing a button or to a table?
Should I load a function into a button like this?

```
<button onclick="">Get Data By Normal XHR</button>
```

If that is the case then should I save the response of the XHR request into an array or const or variable of some sort and display them?
Or is there any other approach I should take to display the XHR response on the HTML dom?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672365/get-data-from-json-api-and-display-it-in-html

check this thread

Comment: Thank you for your response, however they were doing jquery and I am not so I don't think the answers apply to my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example:

```
var url = "https://sourceforge.net/projects/kaais/files/stats/json?start_date=2013-08-18&end_date=2018-04-19";

var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText).total;
}
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.send();
```

Html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="output">NO DATA</div>
</div>
```